# Using titlepage, multiple authors and hyperref with pdfusetitle not possible?

Tags: hyperref

Following code:

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[pdfusetitle]{hyperref}
\title{Test}
 \author{Hans \and Karl}
\begin{document}
 \maketitle
\end{document}
```

Will raise this error:

```
! Use of \end doesn't match its definition.
\and ^^@-\end {
             tabular}\hskip 1em \@plus .17fil\begin {tabular}[t]{c}
l.10 \end
       {document}
?
```

which can be solved by using

```
\author{Hans \texorpdfstring{\and}{,} Karl}
```

Is this a bug in `hyperref`?

A possible solution would be redefining `\and` like this:

```
\let\oldand\and
\renewcommand\and{\texorpdfstring{\oldand}{,}}
```

Or even creating an option like `pdfAuthorDelimiter` and using this instead of and.

Comment: Internally `\and` does some tabular stuff. This would look a bit odd in the document properties. So i think `texorpdfstring` is correct here.

Comment: In my opinion this should be in the package, so a user has not to live with this cryptic error message.

Comment: You can always ask the author to consider a feature request.

Comment: This is a crosspost to [komascript.de](http://www.komascript.de/node/1877) and you got the same answer there as i was going to suggest here and @cfr also did: If you think this is a bug or should be changed, ask [Heiko](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967/heiko-oberdiek).

Comment: i did not find a contact, so I posted it here and supposed he'll see it.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek ping in case you haven't seen. Maybe you can close this.